# Re-open/move closed question

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/3443/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-the-professor-a-trick-question) was closed as not appropriate to the site. I agree with that. But I think it *is* appropriate to academia.stackexchange.com.

I started to cast a re-open vote but that looks boolean & I'm not sure I'll have the opportunity to flag it as needing to be moved *before* it's reopened. And it's really *not* appropriate to re-open it on this site.

So... now what?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to request that something be migrated to a site other than meta, you need to raise a custom flag (**flag** -> **in need of moderator intervention**). Only moderators can migrate questions at this stage to any other site.

You don't need to reopen the question before doing that, though.

If a moderator agrees with your flag, they will reopen the question and migrate it themselves, as their vote is binding<sup>1</sup>. You can still flag, even if you've voted to reopen.

---

<sup>1</sup>What really happens is that voting to migrate closes the question as off-topic, deletes the answers, locks the post and recreates the question and answers on the target site, leaving only a redirecting 'stub' here.

Comment: Of course! Thanks.